# Restkit response descriptor not work when keyPath with url query params

Tags: ios, restkit

I have keyPath like api/v1.2/comment?pid=:pid&text=:text

And then i do call api method through RestKit

```
 RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:nil];
    operation.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryHigh;
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
    [self.objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

Where path replaced to full complete url like

http://localhost/api/v1.2/comment?pid=1&text=Testing

Also i have response descriptor for path api/v1.2/comment?pid=:pid&text=:text

But RestKit tells that can't found response descriptor for path.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Restkit (at the time of writing) query parameters aren't used for response descriptor matching. Remove them from the path pattern on the response descriptor.

If you need the query parameters for mapping then use @metadata.